# C# compression and Delphi decompression

Tags: delphi, zlib, deflatestream

I've some files that were compressed using the C# DeflateStream class like this:

```
using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
```

Nothing fancy, all default values.  It decompresses fine using the equivalent C# DeflateStreamCode i.e.

```
using (DeflateStream decompressionStream = new DeflateStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
```

but I need to decompress this using Delphi.  I've tried the zlib library (XE8, XE10.3), something along these lines:

```
InStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
InStream.LoadFromFile('F:\mycompressedfile.x');
DecompressionStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(InStream);
OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
OutStream.LoadFromStream(DecompressionStream);
OutStream.SaveToFile('F:\mydecompressedfile.x');
```

but keep getting 'data error' messages.  How can I decompress a C# DeflateStream compressed file?

Comment: Did you try the code in Embarcadero documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/ZLibCompressDecompress_(Delphi) ? First try using a standard zip file. Also, did you try to decompress the file created with C# using WinZip or Windows built-in zip handling?

Comment: I did, it works fine if compressed and decompressed using Delphi, but not with a C# compressed file.

Comment: An the file compressed with C#, can it be decompressed using Windows build-in zip file handling (just using the explorer)? Just to validate that compression done by your C# code is standard.

Comment: You should write an answer here to your own question, instead of putting the answer in the question.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to edit a solution into the question. If you've found that solution, you can write it up in the form of an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: fpiette - I wasn't creating zip archives in C#, just compressed files.
Mark and Ken - my apologies, have posted my update as an answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the default settings for the Delphi deflate algorithms expect zlib headers, while the C# deflate code creates 'raw' compressed streams.  Setting up the decompression stream this way (with a -ve value for WindowBits) allows Delphi to decompress the C# compressed data.

```
DecompressionStream := TZDecompressionStream.Create(FBlobStream, -15);
```

As per the official [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.ZLib.TZDecompressionStream.Create):

> The WindowBits parameter determines the buffer handling. Zero indicates the zlib header to determine the buffer size. Values between 8 and 15 set the buffer size, negative values indicate the raw processing, and adding to 16 forces the gzip handling.